# Android PHONEGAP app / cant open in browser

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I have an android app that we are deploying to the problematic BES12 secure workspace. This has a web browser which has to use a proxy.

This app is really simple, it opens a webpage, however it opens using a browser within the app which will not use the proxy settings.

I need this app to open a webpage but using the PHONE BROWSER (i,e outside of the app).

I have read, and followed multiple threads about opening a URL in the phone browser and NOT the app and none of them work.

Here is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"

```
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "(removed for security)"
    version     = "1.1.2"
    versionCode = "10" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />


<name>cURLs</name>

<description>
     FGW Corporate URL Library
</description>

<author href="(removed for security)" email="(removed for security)">
    Morgan
</author>

<icon src="icon.png" />

<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

<access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
```

and here is the app itself (REALLY simple, only in its infancy)

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>
        App Library
    </title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="blue">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">


    <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20%;">
        <img src="icon.png" style="width:50%;">
    </p>
    <h1 class="text-center">
        Welcome to cURLs
    </h1>
    <h2 id="show-once" class="text-center">cURLs is Loading..</h2>
    <p id="slow-button" class="text-center" style="padding-top: 100px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large text-center" onclick="window.open('http://(removed for security)', '_blank', 'location=yes');">Reload cURLs Library</button>
    </p>

</div>

</body>

<script>

    // redirect to google after 5 seconds
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('http://(removed for security)', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }, 2000);


</script>
</html>
```

In essense the first time it runs, it auto opens the URL, but the app will stay in the background to reload latest versions if needed via the button.

All I want this to do is to open the URL OUTSIDE of the app, i.e. in the default browser.

I have also tried a target of "_system"

Many thanks in advance for helping to end this headache

Answer (score 0):

Well. So simple, it bites..

Added the following to my config.xml file

```
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
```

and now done